# I keep getting the following error trying to parse json in python "string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json, parsing

When I use json.loads I get the following error

```
string indices must be integers
```

I was doing some research and saw someone with what I thought was a similar situation. I changed this

```
json.dumps(newstring_two)
```

to this

```
json.loads(json.dumps(newstring_two))
```

but it still did not work. Here is the function I created

```
def panties():
        pan_url = 'http://www.panvideos.com'
        html = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find('div', {'class': 'video-player'})
            entries = [{'text': str(div),
                        } for div in video_row][3]['text']

            oldstring = str(entries)
            removed = '<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer("video-setup").setup('
            newstring = oldstring.replace(removed, "")
            removed_two = ');</script>'
            newstring_two = newstring.replace(removed_two, "")
            parsed_json = json.dumps(newstring_two)
            finishe = parsed_json['file']

            return finishe

        entries = [{'text': div.h4.text,
                    'href': div.a.get('href'),
                    'tube': youtube_link(div.a.get('href')),
                    } for div in video_row][:1]

        return entries
```

but it's not working. What's the issue?

EDIT: my full trace back

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/oku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/oku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/oku/super_nu/src/blog/views.py", line 164, in index
        pan = panties()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/oku/super_nu/src/blog/my_scraps.py", line 166, in panties
        } for div in video_row][:1]
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/oku/super_nu/src/blog/my_scraps.py", line 166, in <listcomp>
        } for div in video_row][:1]
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/oku/super_nu/src/blog/my_scraps.py", line 159, in youtube_link
        finishe = parsed_json['file']
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: `json.dumps()` returns a string.  You can't index a string by a key name as you are doing in `finishe = parsed_json['file']`.

Comment: Also, the variable name `parsed_json` makes me think that you've gotten `json.dumps` and `json.loads` confused.

Comment: @JohnGordon Looks like an answer

Comment: @JohnGordon the variable parsed_json initially used json.loads, but I was getting an error that was talking about double quotes. I saw in hitchhikers guide to python that json.dumps changes the single quotes to double quotes. Json is strict about the quotes

Comment: @losee `json.dumps` doesn't change any quotes; it turns a data structure into a (JSON formatted) string.

Comment: @melpomene right and json is formatted with double quotes. My output was single quotes, so when I used json.dumps that error about quotes went away I got it from here http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/

Comment: @losee Yes, it makes the error go away, but it also does something completely different. You might as well call `len(newstring_two)`, which also makes the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

'newstring_two' is string, so `parsed_json = json.dumps(newstring_two)` should be replaced `parsed_json = json.loads(newstring_two)`. 
see [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: when I do what you mentioned and do this parsed_json['file'] I get the following error message "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Comment: `newstring_two` is not standard json string. If you just get `file` field，you can use re. for example `tube_file = re.search('file:"(.*?)",',  new_string_two)
print(tube_file.group(1))`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a integer instead of 'file' statement at that line:

```
finishe = parsed_json['file']
```

So, it can be so:

```
finishe = parsed_json[0]
```

The 0 number at example can be 1,2,3,4 ..... You must find out which is the true number.

Comment: Thanks for responding but that doesn't work. Doing that only returns a single character. The output of doing that would be "{"

Comment: try that:
str = ""
for i in parsed_json:
    str+=i
print str

what do you see when you do it ?